# SNMP MIB subtree registering and unregistering

Tags: python, pysnmp

I've a collector that collects data through SNMP. I'm using **Python 3** and **pysnmp** module. I've used pysnmp module to collect data. I've encountered following exception.

`MIB subtree (subtree oid) not registered at MIBTree((1,), None)`

`OID I'm searching for: 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0`

On pysnmp source, I've find following lines but I don't know how it's done.

```
# This may fail if you fill a table by exporting MibScalarInstances
# but later drop them through SNMP.
#
# Tree traversal
#
# Missing branches are indicated by the NoSuchObjectError exception.
```

I think it's probable that someone has unregistered MIB subtree using net-snmp.

I'm new to SNMP and on surface I know how SNMP works.

Basically, I'm trying to recreate this issue by unregistering OIDs but so far I've found is this
http://www.net-snmp.org/dev/agent/group__agent__mib__registering.

Can someone help me, or at least point me to some direction or materials.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [the code](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.py#L443), it seems you are trying to unregister a subtree twice *or* after this subtree has been deleted via SNMP SET operation on a SNMP table `RowStatus` object.

It's hard to tell anything beyond that without seeing a reproducer.